# Why do we use"/etc/init.d/process start"

Tags: linux, shell

Why do we use `/etc/init.d/httpd start` in the below program? Why can't we use `service httpd start`? For me it's showing as unrecognized service. (I have installed httpd already.)

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $(ps -ef | grep httpd | wc -l) > 1 ))
then
   echo "httpd is running!!!"
else
   /etc/init.d/httpd start
fi
```

Comment: replace that $service with httpd. sorry for the mistake

Comment: you should edit your question to fix the mistake.

Comment: your question is not really answerable because *we* don't what's the context of the script that you have listed in OP

Comment: the context of the script is to check whether apache is running and if not start it.simple

Comment: Err if that script is used by `service` itself then `service` won't call itself because that would simply call *this* script again, and woopsies we have an infinite loop :P ... If it's not being called by `service` then you can replace the line in question with `service httpd start`. Which is why I was asking, in what *context* is the script being called. The meaning of the script was already clear

Comment: fine fine.my question is simple. why are we using "/etc/init.d/httpd start" instead of "service httpd start" (I'am a beginner in shell scripting)

Answer (score -1):

:-) vishal I don't mean to frustrate you. However, it's difficult to answer your question without a lot of assumptions.

### Some considerations for *not* using `/etc/init.d/httpd start`

- hard-coded location
- assumes that *httpd* is stored in file /etc/init.d/httpd and not say *apache2* or *nginx* or something else.
- even the `ps -ef` test assumes the process name to be httpd and sometimes it's not

### Some considerations for *not* using `service httpd start`

There *may also be* good reasons for *not* using `service httpd start` in this script because it may have side effects. For example,

- `service` may not have *httpd* registered as a service
- if you use `service` you may end up relaunching other dependent services which you may not want to do
- `service` may bury the errors during start up and you may want to.